# Non-greedy match from end of string with regsub

Tags: regex, tcl, non-greedy

I have a folder path like following:

```
/h/apps/new/app/k1999
```

I want to remove the `/app/k1999` part with the following regular expression:

```
set folder "/h/apps/new/app/k1999"
regsub {\/app.+$} $folder "" new_folder
```

But the result is `/h`: too many elements are being removed.

I noticed that I should use non-greedy matching, so I change the code to:

```
regsub {\/app.+?$} $folder "" new_folder
```

but the result is still `/h`.
What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Does this `/app/k1999` substring only appear at the end of the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-greedy simply means that it will try to match the least amount of characters and increase that amount if the whole regex didn't match. The opposite - greedy - means that it will try to match as much characters as it can and reduce that amount if the whole regex didn't match.

`$` in regex means the end of the string. Therefore `something.+$` and `something.+?$` will be equivalent, it is just that one will do more retries before it matches.

In your case `/app.+` is matched by `/apps` and this is the first occurrence of `/app` in your string. You can fix it by being more explicit and adding the `/` that follows `/app`:

```
regsub {/app/.+$} $folder "" new_folder
```

Comment: no need to escape `/` in regex. It has no special meaning

Comment: @slebetman, thanks. I was not sure if there was something specific to tlc that OP had in mind. After some testing it works just fine. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to match `app` as a whole word, you can make use of the [word boundaries](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M30) that in Tcl are `\m` and `\M`:

> `\m`
>  
>   matches only at the beginning of a word 
>   `\M`
>  matches only at the end of a word

We only need the `\M` as `/` is a non-word character and we do not need `\m`:

```
set folder "/h/apps/new/app/k1999"
regsub {/app\M.+$} $folder "" newfolder
puts $newfolder
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/5FQEFz)

Result: `/h/apps/new` (we remove everything from a whole word `app` up to the end.)

If you want to remove just a part of the string inside the path, you can use negated class `[^/]+` to make sure you only [match a subpart of a path](http://ideone.com/UFM5LN):

```
regsub {/app/[^/]+} $folder "" newfolder
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use a regular expression substitution operation to remove a directory suffix from a path name, but that doesn't mean you *should*.

```
file join {*}[lmap dir [file split $folder] {if {$dir ne {app}} {set dir} break}]
# -> /h/apps/new
```

A path name is a string, but more properly it's a list of directory names:

```
file split $folder
# -> / h apps new app k1999
```

What you want is the sublist of directory names up to, but not including, the directory named "app".

```
lmap dir [file split $folder] {if {$dir ne {app}} {set dir} break}
# -> / h apps new
```

(The directory name can be tested however you wish; a couple of possibilities are `{$dir ni {foo app bar}}` to skip at alternative names, or `{![string match app-* $dir]}` for any name beginning with "app-".)

And when you've gotten the list of directory names you wanted, you join the elements of it back to a path name again, as above.

So why should you do it this way instead of by using a regular expression substitution operation? This question illustrates the problem well. Unless one is an RE expert or takes great care to read the documentation, one is likely to formulate a regular expression based on a hunch. In the worst case, it works the first time. If not, one is tempted to tinker with it until it does. And any sufficiently ununderstood (yep, that *is* a word) RE will seem to work most of the time with occasional false positives and negatives to keep things interesting.

Split it, truncate it, join it. Can't go wrong. And if it does, it goes obviously wrong, forcing you to fix it.

Documentation: [break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression engine *always* starts matching as soon as it can; the greediness doesn't affect this. This means that in this case, it always starts matching too soon; you want the last match, not the first one.

If you use `regexp -all -indices -inline`, you can find out where the last match starts. That lets you then remove the part you actually don't want (e.g., by replacing it with an empty string:

```
set folder "/h/apps/new/app/k1999"
set indices [regexp -all -indices -inline {/app} $folder]
# This gets this value: {2 5} {11 14}

# If we have indices — if we had a match — we can do the rest of our processing
if {[llength $indices] > 0} {
    # Get the '11'; the first sub-element of the last element
    set index [lindex $indices end 0]
    # Replace '/app/k1999' with the empty string
    set newfolder [string replace $folder $index end ""]
} else {
    set newfolder $folder;   # In case there's no match...
}
```

Comment: Note that this technique is independent of choosing a good regular expression _and it depends on having no capturing sub-expressions in the RE_. Be careful with those (parentheses) and if you have to have them, use `end-1`, `end-2`, etc. as necessary in the extracting `lindex`.